# Reduce image dimensions php

Tags: php, html

I'm looking to reduce image sizes using PHP on page load. I'm not really to sure how to achieve this, i've gotten as far as to obtain the dimensions but how would I reduce the sizes of these using only PHP?Here is my current code:

```
<?php 
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM img_gallery ORDER BY list');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  : 
$image =  $row['url'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image); //grab the image dimensions here
?>  

<img src="" width="<?=$width ?>px" height="<?=$height ?>px" /> //image here
```

So the dimensions are reduced by a few hundred pixels each?

Comment: What's the issue? Just divide the values by whatever you wish for them to be

Comment: phpThumb() is the PHP thumbnail generator Link - http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php

Comment: You mean like <img src="" width="<?=$width / 10 ?>px" height="<?=$height / 10 ?>px" />
?

Comment: if you want to reduce the image size of the image and not in the img tag, then you should edit images using GD library functions. Check here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: i think this will sort your problem http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Comment: thanks guys, @Mati was a simple solution that worked. I don't see as to why I am down voted when I asked a question and have some great answers.

Answer (score 0):

try php `imagejpeg`

```
imagejpeg (resource $image [,string $filename [,int $quality ] ] );
```

For more info click [here](http://www.php.net/function.imagejpeg),

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new canvas with the desired size and copy the resampled canvas there:

```
$newcanvas = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
$oldcanvas = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
imagecopyresampled($newcanvas,$oldcanvas,0,0,0,0,$width, $height,$originalwidth,$originalheight);
```